# Matrix form of Fourier and Fresnel Transform

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am wondering how to write up the matrix form of, say, Fresnel or Fourier transform. I know that for the case of Fresnel it would be Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix form"?

Comment: I mean matrix for discrete calculations. For example, wave propagation can be shown in the matrix form as E2=P*E1, where P is the propagation operator in the matrix form and that is the Fresnel propagation. So if E1 is the input field and diagonal matrix, then P, a Toeplitz matrix acts on it to give E2.

Comment: Are you talking about a DFT matrix? If so, a search engine will give you more than enough resources.

Comment: Thanks. I could find many on DFT but not much for Fresnel Transform.